# Save vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet python

Tags: python, xml, save, xlsx, spreadsheetml

I have a file that is extracted through an API in the following form:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

that I want to save to my computer. I'm using Python to save this xlsx file, but no success so far.

Anyone who can help me in the right directions.

Thanks a lot!